# how to disable a item in radtreeview contextmenu

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to disable the following item1 in the ContextMenu. But I dind't find any relevant property for it in IntelliSense.

```
Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeViewContextMenu.ContextMenu contextMenu1 = new Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeViewContextMenu.ContextMenu();
contextMenu1.Name = "Menu";
Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeViewContextMenu.ContextMenuItem Item1 = new Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeViewContextMenu.ContextMenuItem();
Item1.Text = "Add New Item";
Item1.ID = "Add"; 

//Here i want to make this Item1 Enable false

contextMenu1.Items.Add(Item1); 
RadTreeView1.ContextMenus.Add(contextMenu1);
```

Comment: this code seems like it uses extremely old versions (probably something from around 2006) that maybe do not have that feature yet

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Telerik.Web.UI;` ? Because i'm using that i can easily get the intellisense to disabled the control.

Here is the code

.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Test"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

.cs

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeViewContextMenu context = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeViewContextMenu();
context.Items.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuItem("Enabled", "http://www.google.com"));
context.Items.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuItem("Disable", "http://www.google.com"));

// Check
if (context.Items.Count > 0)
    context.Items[context.Items.Count - 1].Enabled = false;

RadTreeView1.ContextMenus.Add(context);
```

Result 
[image]